# Requirements to consume a SOAP web service

Tags: android, eclipse, requirements

I am new to consume web service in android eclipse.Currently i am following the below link
http://jatin4rise.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/webservicecallfromandroid/
But not its working.

Can anyone tell what are the requirements to consume the SOAP web service from android eclipse.

Thanks for any HELP!!

Comment: I think you should also try to visit links given in the comments in your link.It may also help you to gather requirements.

Comment: Please give people credit for their effort to help you and [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/164138) on your previous questions. You haven't accepted a single answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ksoap. It is easy to implement. refer below link for sample program.

[Sample Program](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html)